# Is there a Watch list in Flash CS4's AS3 debugger?

Tags: actionscript-3, debugging, flash-cs4

Is a watch list hidden away somewhere in the AS3 debugger in Flash CS4?

Sorry for asking a simple question like this here - I did spend a while looking around the net first.  It's much easier to find the watch list in the AS2 debugger.

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whis AS3, there is no more watch list. Adobe Livedoc suggests to use the Proxy pattern with setter and getter.

Here is a class that does the same as the watch object and is easier to use than the proxy:

```
package
{
   import flash.events.Event;
   import flash.events.EventDispatcher;
   public class Model extends EventDispatcher
   {
       public static const VALUE_CHANGED:String = 'value_changed';
       private var _number:Number = Number;
       public function Model():void
       {
           trace('The model was instantiated.');
       }
       public function set number(newNb:Number):void
       {
          _number=newNb;
          this.dispatchEvent(new Event(Model.VALUE_CHANGED));
       }
       public function get number():Number
      {
          return _number;

      }
   }
}
```

The `_number` variable and variable type can be replaced by whatever type is needed.

The usage:

```
var objectToWatch:Model = new Model();
objectToWatch.addEventListener(Model.VALUE_CHANGED, onValuedChanged);

function onValuedChanged(e:Event) {
   //do what you need here
}
```

Comment: Thanks o15a3d4l11s2.  That's interesting and will be useful if I really need to get stuck into an object to debug it.

It would be nice if Adobe could add a watch list back in again, for more casual scenarios, and perhaps also add the ability to mouse over properties and fields in the debugger to see their values.

Comment: So basically, there is no way to "watch" a property of an *existing* object definition in AS3 like there was in AS2.  You must instead modify the object's class definition, adding trace statements into its getters and setters, or change the base class of every object you want to watch to some custom implementation of "Proxy" that overrides the "setProperty" method to trace or dispatch events when the value changes... sure.